# NSArray randomly turning into different things!

Tags: iphone, memory, nsarray, uitouch

I am having a problem with memory management I think. My NSArray (called arr) is turning into different things at random times. I have no idea why. I have a .h file that that declares the array, and then I initialize the array using

```
NSString *input = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSACIIStringEncoding];
arr = [input componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"];
```

and then I use it throughout the program and suddenly it changes into different things (UITouch, sometimes, for example). I never called a release on it. Why is it doing this? How do I prevent objects from randomly being changed due to memory issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to retain *arr*.

```
arr = [[input componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"] retain];
```

Comment: This is correct, the reason this happens is because 'componentsSeperatedByString' returns an autoreleased object. Once the array retain count hits zero the object is deallocated and that memory is now free to be occupied by the next object that needs it. Hence why you seems it is "turning into different things".

Comment: But now I am getting memory leaks.

Comment: @Robert: always try to understand things instead of blindly following advice from strangers (like in the real world)

Comment: I did try to understand it. However I believe it has to do with this method "components seperated by string." I understand the ideas behind memory release it is just that I'm not an expert. I come from the world of Java, where memory management is built in and is more smart than it is here. Now, how can I prevent this memory leak? I initialize the array once, and I release it in the dealloc. How are there leaks?

Comment: "more smart" could also be "more dumb" depending on the perspective. I cannot see what happens in your code on the larger scale. Maybe you run this line more than once, in which case you *will* have a leak since you don't release it as many times. Using the getter/setter approach (as in my answer, which you maybe found too long to read, but did get all the upvotes) this is solved automagically.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your post. I did read it all though. Would you mind explaining yourself a little better?

Comment: @Robert: I've been saying more than 1 kb here, maybe you should formulate a question, about what statement or aspect of the system you don't understand, rather than asking me to elaborate even more. There's one thing I left out on purpose, to keep things a little cleaner, and that's `autorelease`. Just search around for it (here and/or in google), there's tons of questions about cocoa memory management. Most answers are high quality.

Answer (score 2):

What happens, is that the memory, once occupied by your NSArray, is occupied by another object. This may be any object, and since you're touching the screen a lot a UITouch is very common.

This means you're not retaining the NSArray when you should, so it is released prematurely. You don't show the code declaring `arr`, but if you declare arr as

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *arr;
```

and synthesize it using

```
@synthesize arr;
```

then the retaining is handled by simply assiging to `self.arr` instead of `arr`:

```
self.arr = [input componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"];
```

In cocoa-speak, your object now "owns" the array. In the `dealloc` method of this class, you should `[self.arr release]`.

Should you assign some other array to `self.arr`, the object assigned to `self.arr` previously will get released, and the new one retained.

Answer (score 0):

Or Initalize a new Array with this array:

```
arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:input];
```

Comment: thus introducing a memory leak.